# ImportError: No module named flask.ext.uploads.UploadSet

Tags: upload, flask

Following the [documentation](http://flask-uploads.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) I have installed Flask-Upload. when trying to import it: `from flask.ext.uploads import UploadSet, IMAGES` it raises an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/home/proj/app/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from app.admin.views import admin
  File "/home/proj/app/admin/views.py", line 14, in <module>
        from flask.ext.uploads import UploadSet, Images
  ImportError: cannot import name Images
```

What is the issue about?

Comment: apparently there are 2 different extensions both called Flask-Uploads by different authors. ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (notice the omitted dot)

```
flaskext.uploads import UploadSet, IMAGES
```

Flask or Flask uploads has changed the path

Edit:

Imports are casesensitive. You should be importing `IMAGES` instead.

Comment: I uninstalled the package and installed it again. And it worked. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like the latest version has a new import location, which I was able to find in the Flask-WTF docs: https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/form.html#validation

Answer (score 2):

Flask provides a simpler option with out the need for extension. Refer below documentation.
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/

here is my implementation following the details in the link

## Imports

```
import os
from werkzeug import secure_filename
from flask import send_from_directory

#app config
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(__file__)
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif','doc','docx','xls'])


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] =  os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER,'uploads') # uploads folder should exists in the server

#function that checks the file extension
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

#function that handles the document upload page
@app.route('/input_docs/<contract_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def input_docs(contract_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], contract_id+'_'+ filename))
        else: 
            flash("Not a valid file %s" % file.filename)    


    contract = Contracts.query.filter_by(id = contract_id).first()
    try:    
        attachments = [file[file.find('_')+1::] for file in os.listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']) if file.startswith(contract_id+'_')]  # Strip out the contract id for from display

    except OSError as err:
        attachments = []    

    doc_form = InputDocsForm(obj=contract)        
    return render_template('input_docs.html',title = 'Input Docs', form=doc_form,attachments=attachments)
```

## function that handles select document download

```
@app.route('/download_docs/<filename>')
def download_docs(filename):

    app.logger.info("Downloading %s"% os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],  filename))
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                                filename)
```

//client side template

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span3">
   <p><input type=file name=file>
</div>
<div class="span3">   
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
</div>      
<div class="span3">      
      <a href="{{ url_for('contracts_list') }}"> <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="{{ _('Close') }}"></a>
      <input id = 'download' class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="{{ _('Download') }}">
</div>

</div>

<table class="table">  
        <thead>  
          <tr>  
            <th>Select</th>  
            <th>Attachment</th>  
          </tr>  
        </thead>  
        <tbody>  

        {% for attachment in attachments %}
          <tr>
          <td >{{ attachment }}</td>
          <td id = "sel" onclick = 'onSelectDoc( "{{attachment}}"  )'> {{ form.sel ( type ="checkbox" ) }} </td>

          </tr>

    {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
     </table>
```

//client side javascript

```
<script>
var Attachments = [];

$( document ).ready(function(){
   $( "#download" ).click(function() {
   if (Attachments.length > 0){
            var contract_id = document.getElementById('id').value;    
            var url =  flask_util.url_for('download_docs' ,{ filename:contract_id+"_"+Attachments[0]  } );
            var k = Attachments.length;
            while (k--)  Attachments.shift();

            $(location).attr('href',url); 



        }
    else{
        alert("Select at least one attachment to download");
        return;

    }    

    });



function onSelectDoc(attachment){


if (attachment.length>0) {
   var i = Attachments.indexOf(attachment)
   if (i>=0 ) {
        Attachments.splice(i,1) ; //remove the attachment on unselect
        return;
        }
}        
Attachments.push(attachment);

} 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install -e "git://github.com/FelixLoether/flask-uploads#egg=Flask-Uploads"
```

Source:
http://flask-uploads.readthedocs.org/en/latest/